# Adding a static header in a csv file to fill all rows with a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am collecting names and numbers and exporting it into a csv file.

column A is = names
column B is = numbers

How can I get column c to fill all rows with "Phoenix" so that every column that has a name or number in it column c would say phoenix?

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


realtor_data = []

for page in range(1, 6):
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")
    url = f"https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-{page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

    for agent_card in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "agent-list-card clearfix"}):
        name = agent_card.find("div", {"class": "agent-name text-bold"}).find("a")
        number = agent_card.find("div", {"itemprop": "telephone"})
        realtor_data.append(
            [
                name.getText().strip(),
                number.getText().strip() if number is not None else "N/A"
                
             ],
        )

with open("data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(["NAME:", "PHONE NUMBER:", "CITY:"])
    w.writerows(realtor_data)
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the columns c with phoenix.

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


realtor_data = []

for page in range(1, 6):
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")
    url = f"https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-{page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

    for agent_card in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "agent-list-card clearfix"}):
        name = agent_card.find("div", {"class": "agent-name text-bold"}).find("a")
        number = agent_card.find("div", {"itemprop": "telephone"})
        realtor_data.append(
            [
                name.getText().strip(),
                number.getText().strip() if number is not None else "N/A"
                
             ],
        )

with open("data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(["NAME:", "PHONE NUMBER:", "CITY:"])
    w.writerows(realtor_data)

import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
a2 = a.iloc[:,[0,1]]
a3 = a.iloc[:,[2]]
a3 = a3.fillna("phoenix")
b=pd.concat([a2,a3],axis=1)
b.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Comment: File "pageloop.py", line 24, in <module>
    w = csv.writer(output)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined : this is the error i am recieving!

Comment: You get that error because the csv library is not imported.

Answer (score 0):

So, you could do this to your code to make all have a City of Phoenix:

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


realtor_data = []

for page in range(1, 6):
    print(f"Scraping page {page}...")
    url = f"https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-{page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

    for agent_card in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "agent-list-card clearfix"}):
        name = agent_card.find("div", {"class": "agent-name text-bold"}).find("a")
        number = agent_card.find("div", {"itemprop": "telephone"})
        data_list = []
        if name:
            data_list.append(name.getText().strip())
        else:
            data_list.append("N/A")
        if number:
            data_list.append(number.getText().strip())
        else:
            data_list.append("N/A")
        data_list.append('Phoenix')
        realtor_data.append(data_list)

with open("data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(["NAME:", "PHONE NUMBER:", "CITY:"])
    w.writerows(realtor_data)
```

You may want to look into pandas.DataFrame object and appending a dictionary containing values for each field to it since that will make accessing the data much easier instead of stepping through a csv file.

*Edited to ensure you always have exactly 3 items in your rows even if you don't have a valid number or name and changed one-liner if else syntax

Comment: Hey this kinda worked however it only added Phoenix tag to the lines that were missing a phone number. Sorry if maybe my question was worded poorly. I am trying to get all columns on the right side of name and number to say phoenix